# Nginx returns "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Tags: nginx

- My host machine is a macbookpro m2
- I installed centos stream 9 on the host machine using Paralls Desktop 19, and installed nginx-1.23.1 on centos
- I turned off the firewall on both centos and the host machine
- Paralls Desktop uses the shared network mode, and I can ping external addresses successfully on centos
- nginx.conf listens on port 80, and the result of running “lsof -i tcp:80” on centos shows only nginx
- After starting nginx, I can get a successful response from nginx by running “curl 10.211.56.88” on centos; but when I visit “10.211.56.88” on the browser of the host machine, it always fails, responding with “ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE”
- The network configuration of my Paralls Desktop is shown in the following picture
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3PQ9.png)

I can’t figure out where the problem is, and I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: I just visited nginx with the browser again and found that it successful… I didn’t do anything, and I don’t know what caused it to fail all the time before